# How to deploy a react app with json server on Netlify?

Tags: reactjs, netlify, json-server

Does anyone know how to deploy a react app to Netlify? I have db.json file as my fake database, and data posted in "Fake API" using JSON-Server, so how to deploy them to Netlify and host the website?

Comment: In the meantime, have you perhaps found a solution? I have the same problem.